# How to align labels properly using System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting

Tags: model-view-controller, charts, dotnetcharting

I have a chart which generated through System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting. 
Below is the code

```
public ActionResult MBRRChart()
    {
        //Area for generating chart type Range bar
        List<dummyGraph> objGraphList = new List<dummyGraph>();
        dummyGraph objDummyGraph = new dummyGraph();
        objDummyGraph.TKFEType = "Underwriter";
        objDummyGraph.min = 1;
        objDummyGraph.max = 8;
        objDummyGraph.Median = "1";
        objGraphList.Add(objDummyGraph);

        objDummyGraph = new dummyGraph();
        objDummyGraph.TKFEType = "Construction";
        objDummyGraph.min = 2;
        objDummyGraph.max = 5;
        objDummyGraph.Median = "2";
        objGraphList.Add(objDummyGraph);

        objDummyGraph = new dummyGraph();
        objDummyGraph.TKFEType = "Design";
        objDummyGraph.min = 3;
        objDummyGraph.max = 6;
        objDummyGraph.Median = "3";
        objGraphList.Add(objDummyGraph);

        objDummyGraph = new dummyGraph();
        objDummyGraph.TKFEType = "Partner";
        objDummyGraph.min = 4;
        objDummyGraph.max = 6;
        objDummyGraph.Median = "3";
        objGraphList.Add(objDummyGraph);

        objDummyGraph = new dummyGraph();
        objDummyGraph.TKFEType = "Construction";
        objDummyGraph.min = 2;
        objDummyGraph.max = 5;
        objDummyGraph.Median = "2";
        objGraphList.Add(objDummyGraph);

        objDummyGraph = new dummyGraph();
        objDummyGraph.TKFEType = "Design";
        objDummyGraph.min = 3;
        objDummyGraph.max = 6;
        objDummyGraph.Median = "3";
        objGraphList.Add(objDummyGraph);

        objDummyGraph = new dummyGraph();
        objDummyGraph.TKFEType = "Partner";
        objDummyGraph.min = 4;
        objDummyGraph.max = 6;
        objDummyGraph.Median = "3";
        objGraphList.Add(objDummyGraph);

        objDummyGraph = new dummyGraph();
        objDummyGraph.TKFEType = "Construction";
        objDummyGraph.min = 2;
        objDummyGraph.max = 5;
        objDummyGraph.Median = "2";
        objGraphList.Add(objDummyGraph);

        objDummyGraph = new dummyGraph();
        objDummyGraph.TKFEType = "Design";
        objDummyGraph.min = 3;
        objDummyGraph.max = 6;
        objDummyGraph.Median = "3";
        objGraphList.Add(objDummyGraph);

        objDummyGraph = new dummyGraph();
        objDummyGraph.TKFEType = "Partner";
        objDummyGraph.min = 4;
        objDummyGraph.max = 6;
        objDummyGraph.Median = "3";
        objGraphList.Add(objDummyGraph);

        objDummyGraph = new dummyGraph();
        objDummyGraph.TKFEType = "Construction";
        objDummyGraph.min = 2;
        objDummyGraph.max = 5;
        objDummyGraph.Median = "2";
        objGraphList.Add(objDummyGraph);

        objDummyGraph = new dummyGraph();
        objDummyGraph.TKFEType = "Design";
        objDummyGraph.min = 3;
        objDummyGraph.max = 6;
        objDummyGraph.Median = "3";
        objGraphList.Add(objDummyGraph);

        objDummyGraph = new dummyGraph();
        objDummyGraph.TKFEType = "Partner";
        objDummyGraph.min = 4;
        objDummyGraph.max = 6;
        objDummyGraph.Median = "3";
        objGraphList.Add(objDummyGraph);

        System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart chart1 = new System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart();
        System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea chartArea1 = new System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea();
        System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Legend legend1 = new System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Legend();
        System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Series seriesInstance;

        chart1.Titles.Add("Market Based Rate Range");//Add chart title 

        //chart series initialization
        seriesInstance = new System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Series("xAxis");
        seriesInstance.ChartType = SeriesChartType.RangeBar;//Set chart type here
        seriesInstance.Color = Color.SkyBlue;
        seriesInstance.YValuesPerPoint = 2;
        seriesInstance.SmartLabelStyle.Enabled = true;
        seriesInstance.IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
        //END

        chart1.Series.Add(seriesInstance);

        //Bind values to chart
        chart1.DataSource = objGraphList;
        chart1.Series[0].XValueMember = "TKFEType";
        chart1.Series[0].YValueMembers = "min, max";
        chart1.Series[0].Label = "#VALY <-> #VALY2";

        chart1.DataBind();
        //END

        chart1.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea1);
        chartArea1 = chart1.ChartAreas[0];

        //Used to hide Grid lines
        chartArea1.AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
        chartArea1.AxisX.MinorGrid.Enabled = false;
        chartArea1.AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
        chartArea1.AxisY.MinorGrid.Enabled = false;
        //END

        //Used to hide the x axis values
        chartArea1.AxisY.Enabled = AxisEnabled.False;
        //END

        //END

        //Area for returning created chart as image file
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            chart1.SaveImage(ms, ChartImageFormat.Png);
            return File(ms.ToArray(), "image/png");
        }
        //END
    }
    //END
```

When i run the above code my chart will looks like following image

[image]

In that image you can see that Yaxis labels and bar is not aligning properly (In the same line)

Why it is like so

Comment: If you're referring to the label outside the bar, the bar is too narrow to fit string "4 <-> 6" inside it.

Answer (score 1):

Like i said in my previous comment, your range bar in some cases is too narrow to contain the label, so the chart puts it outside. I tried some of the properties in `SmartLabelStyle` and also `CustomProperties` but none of them seem to have any effect.

Regarding the vertical alignment along Y-Axis,  my suggestion is to not have duplicates. Create multiple `List<DummyGraph>` and bind each one to its own chart `Series`. This way there's no duplicates and everything aligns and looks much better.

Here:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Just creating some random data
        Random r = new Random();
        DummyGraphList data1 = new DummyGraphList(r);
        DummyGraphList data2 = new DummyGraphList(r);

        //Bind each list to its own series
        Chart1.Series[0].Points.DataBind(data1, "TKFType", "Min,Max", null);
        Chart1.Series[1].Points.DataBind(data2, "TKFType", "Min,Max", null);
    }
```

Result:

[image]